# c++ mfc library issue on 2003

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i have compiled a program using microsoft visual 6.0, the program is using MFC librarys but the problem im getting is that is it running fine on my system (windows 7) but not on my other system (windows 2003).

The error that pops up is "could not load MFC42D link library" on the windows 2003, i'm aware that i could just download that dll and use it with the program, but i shouldn't need to as i have included it in my program, is there any download that i need for the windows 2003 system so that it can run?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are linking your application with the debug versions of the MFC library.  The debug versions of the MFC library are not redistributable (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260978%28v=VS.60%29.aspx).  So link with the non-debug versions instead.

Second, if you dynamically link with MFC, you need to distribute the MFC DLL's as well.  Look in the folders where you installed Visual Studio.  There should be an installer for MFC and the C Runtime somewhere.

If running an installer on your customers' computers is a problem for you, you might want to consider linking statically with MFC.  Look in the Visual Studio help for the exact compiler and linker flags.